# Getting Webdav Working

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, webdav

It's being a week I'm trying to get webdav working on a Vhost without any success....
**Here is my setup:**
Debian 9
Apache 2.4
Virtualmin 6.01

```
SuexecUserGroup "#1039" "#1038"
ServerName dav.mydom.com
DocumentRoot /home/dav/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/dav.mydom.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/dav.mydom.com_access_log combined
<Directory "/home/dav/public_html">
 Options Indexes MultiViews
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /webdav /home/dav/public_html
<location /webdav>
 Dav on
 AuthType Basic
 AuthBasicProvider file
 AuthName "WebDav"
 AuthUserFile /home/dav/public_html/.htpasswd
 <Limit GET PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user
 </Limit>
</location>
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://localhost:8005/home/dav/public_html/$1
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.0
php_admin_value engine Off
```

Trying to test it with cadaver, I got the message I can't even enter my user name and pass

```
[matth@www ~]# cadaver http://dav.mydom.com/webdav/
Authentication required for WebDav on server `dav.mydom.com':
Username: 
Authentication aborted!
Could not open collection:
Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge
dav:/webdav/?
```

I have also tested by creating a .netrc pass to authenticate automatically but i good this then:

```
[matth@www ~]# cadaver https://dav.mydom.com/webdav
Could not access /webdav/ (not WebDAV-enabled?):
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection to `db.ducorporation.com' closed.
dav:!>
```

**access.log**

```
s.r.c.ip - - [18/Jan/2018:04:03:29 +0100] "OPTIONS /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4236 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
s.r.c.ip - - [18/Jan/2018:04:03:30 +0100] "HEAD /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 620 "https://app.dom.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
s.r.c.ip - - [18/Jan/2018:04:03:31 +0100] "OPTIONS /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 1146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
s.r.c.ip - - [18/Jan/2018:04:03:32 +0100] "HEAD /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 620 "https://app.dom.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
s.r.c.ip - - [18/Jan/2018:04:03:32 +0100] "OPTIONS /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 1146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
s.r.c.ip - - [18/Jan/2018:04:03:33 +0100] "PUT /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 405 938 "https://app.dom.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
```

**error.log** is empty

With suexec i'm making sure Apache is running under the proper user, also the access to any files does work from a Web browser after authentication.
Also tested
- not to use `location` but `directory`
- Disable Directory indexing
- Auth none/Digest/Basic
- Webdav folder at the route of the DocumentRoot as well as sub-folder
- Changed ownership of the public_html folder to the apache user
- Some other thing i don't remember

*With all these tests, I'm getting the same error*

Done my testing with Firefox/litmus/cadaver/webdav client app
With Firefox and the webdav app I'm able to read and download files but not edit `PUT` get as a `405 error` (meaning `PUT` is not allowed, but it's allowed in my `<Limit>` section) 
With litmus/cadaver no chance to do anything so far…

Hope I'm clear enough
Any input would be much appreciated

EDIT: apache logs added

Matth

Comment: And not a single hint in `/var/log/virtualmin/dav.mydom.com_error_log` ?

Comment: Is this syntax understood by Apache: `SuexecUserGroup "#1039" "#1038"`?

Comment: I'm with Gerard, what does the error log say? Without that feedback you are going blind.

Comment: From my testing the logs are saying exactly the same as the client ``error 405``, as per suexec Apache doesn't complaint at all about it.  I'll post the logs as soon as I have rerun a bunch of tests.

Comment: Okey I have added the Apache logs

Comment: If the errors are not in that error log, they must be in another one.  You should at least have messages from when you restarted or reloaded Apache.

Comment: Okey, interesting let me look at that with new tests

Comment: Ok, after fighting again with is I realize, I was editing the config file for http instead of the port 443…  This is the downside of using tools like Virtualmin and you don't have a full understanding of what you are doing…  Next step is to fix the authentication issue…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I finally manage to get it work:
This config is working for Apache 2.4 for the **SSL** vhost, the **HTTP** one redirect to **SSL**.
I had to set a dedicated folder where the Apache user has dedicated read/write access.

To be more secure I wish to have Apache running as a specific user but it seems the easiest way today is to use `MPM-ITK` which is apparently not compatible with `MPM-Prefork` module that I'm using now.
Will give a try once I understand the consequences of moving from `MPM-Prefork` to ``MPM-ITK`.

Any comment for security improvement are welcome !

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, content-type, cache-control, accept, authorization, if-match, destination, overwrite"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "ETag"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, MOVE, DELETE, COPY, LOCK, UNLOCK"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"

RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.html [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]
ServerName my.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/www/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/my.domain.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/my.domain.com_access_log combined
DavLockDB /home/www/public_html/DavLock
<Directory /home/www/public_html>
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
Options Indexes MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /webdav /home/www/public_html

<Location "/webdav">
 Dav on
 DirectoryIndex none
 AuthType Basic
 AuthBasicProvider file
 AuthUserFile /home/www/public_html/.htpasswd
 AuthName "WebDav"
 <Limit GET HEAD POST PUT OPTIONS MOVE DELETE COPY LOCK UNLOCK>
  Require valid-user
 </Limit>
 <Limit  OPTIONS>
  Require all granted
 </Limit>
DavDepthInfinity off
</Location>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/my/ssl.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/my/ssl.key
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCACertificateFile /home/my/ssl.ca
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.0
php_admin_value engine Off
RedirectMatch ^/(?!webdav) "https://my.domain.com/webdav"
```